# Apple JS sign in: Get user id from code and id_token?

Tags: python, apple-sign-in

I need to use Apple signin to log users into my website. All users will already have signed up using Apple signup in the iOS native app. As part of the iOS signup process, Apple provides a user id, which is a unique identifier for that particular user. I save this in my database to identify the user.

How do I get that same Apple user id when a user signs in using Apple JS on the website?

I am using Apple JS as described here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/sign_in_with_apple_js/configuring_your_webpage_for_sign_in_with_apple I have usePopup=false

- The user clicks the *Apple signin with Apple* button and goes through Apple's signin wizard. OK
- Apple sends a POST request to my specified redirectURI. OK
- The post request contains id_token and code. OK

Now, how do I get Apple's user id to identify the actual user who logged in?

Comment: The documentation article you linked includes a section titled [Handle the Authorization Response](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/sign_in_with_apple_js/configuring_your_webpage_for_sign_in_with_apple#3331292), which seems to include the information you're looking for. Can you elaborate as to why this section doesn't include the information you need?

Comment: Because at no point does that section describe how to get the user id from the response.

Comment: Have you checked to ensure it's not included in the `id_token`? Usually a unique identified like the one you desire would be contained in a [JWT](https://jwt.io/introduction) payload as Apple describes in the linked document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The provided id_token contains the Apple user id once it gets decoded.** It has been encoded with JWT. You do NOT need any keys or secrets to decode it. You can, in fact, copy-paste the id_token in here https://jwt.io/ to see the format and all the data it contains.

The Apple user ID is the sub info.

```
// Header
{
  "kid": "AIDOPK1",
  "alg": "RS256"
}
// Payload
{
  "iss": "https://appleid.apple.com",
  "aud": [Same as clientId, same as serivce id],
  "exp": 1579073561,
  "iat": 1579072961,
  "sub": [Apple User Identifier],
  "c_hash": "Q4ZkNP4SB2f-m9vtLfO0UA",
  "email": [EMAIL],
  "email_verified": "true",
  "is_private_email": "true",
  "auth_time": 1579072961
}
```

**About security**

There are some things you should, for security reasons, verify before you just go ahead and use the user_id (provide and check state, check the decoded info) This tutorial talks about that https://sarunw.com/posts/sign-in-with-apple-4/.

**In Python** I installed pyjwt (https://pypi.org/project/PyJWT/)

```
import jwt
decoded = jwt.decode(token, audience="<clientid>",options={"verify_signature": False})
# clientid is what you provided in the call to Apple
user_id = decoded["sub"]
```

*clientid* is what you provided in the call when the user clicked to sign in. This is the same as the service id that you set up in the console for your app. (If you got to the point where you have an id_token, then you'll already have set that up.) I couldn't find a way to decode id-token without providing this info, although it must be possible since the https://jwt.io/ website can do it.